# Filter Array Duplicates On Associative Value

Tags: php

I've got an array:

```
(
[0]
   (
      [room_num] => 1
      [is_event] => true
      [date] => '01/01/2013'
   )
[1]
   (
      [room_num] => 2
      [is_event] => false
      [date] => ''
   )
[2]
   (
      [room_num] => 3
      [is_event] => false
      [date] => ''
   )
[3]
   (
      [room_num] => 1
      [is_event] => false
      [date] => ''
   )
)
```

What I'd like to do is filter the results so that where `is_event = true` supersedes `is_event = false`. My returned array would look like:

```
(
[0]
   (
      [room_num] => 1
      [is_event] => true
      [date] => '01/01/2013'
   )
[1]
   (
      [room_num] => 2
      [is_event] => false
      [date] => ''
   )
[2]
   (
      [room_num] => 3
      [is_event] => false
      [date] => ''
   )
)
```

Sort of like array_unique except ON a certain value.

Is there a built in function for this?

Comment: "Is there a built in function for this?" — No.

Comment: @salathe, is it not a popular enough dilemma to make one?  Seems like something that would come up at least as often as something like array_diff_assoc().

Comment: No, not even nearly "popular enough". In fact, you're the first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in function

You'll have to loop and check yourself

Answer (score 0):

Well, since there is no built in function I wrote it out, loops and all.

In case you're curious how:

```
// @filter is an array of data where (in my case) is_event=0, thus to be filtered
// @keep is an array of data where (again in my case) is_event=1 (data to be kept)
// @$key is the key we will make our comparisons with (in this case is_event)

function filter_assoc_on_key($filter,$keep,$key){

        $tempArr = array();
        $removeArr = array();
        // make an array of the array entries with values matching my key
        foreach($keep as $keeper){
            array_push($tempArr,$keeper[$key]);
        }
        // loop the array i want to filter and add the entries matching my key to the $removeArr
        for($i=0;$i<count($filter);$i++){
            if(in_array($filter[$i][$key],$tempArr)){
                array_push($removeArr,$filter[$i]);
            }
        }
        // merge the arrays so that I have all my values in one place
        $newArr = array_merge($filter,$keep);
        // get the values that are unique
        $goodArr = array_diff_assoc($newArr,$removeArr);

        return $goodArr;
    }
```